# No results sometimes when searching

Tags: bug, search

The title says everything, there are sometimes 0 results when I try to search for something. It's totally regardless of the search term and options (if any).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bmarkdown%5D%20answers%3A0%20closed%3Ano) is an example URL that turns out to be empty sometimes.

[image: no results when searching]

Does this have to do something [with the current maintainance issues](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/958348801315627008)?

Safari 11.0.3, macOS 10.13.3

Comment: Can't reproduce; search works fine for me. Please add more details as to where you use search, what URL that results in, and what you see.

Comment: For example, using the search box from your profile page on Stack Overflow, hitting enter to search for the default (so `user:3151675`), produces [305 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3151675).

Comment: Your sample URL produces 605 results for me, same OS X and Safari versions.

Comment: It *may* have something to do with the maintenance, yes, if there is a time-out in the backend search engine you could end up with an empty result set? I'm just not seeing this myself.

Comment: there is serious trouble: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/958367702015512578

Comment: We're having problems fixing search because we can't search for answers to our problems. Should be fixed right after we're done setting random things on fire to see if anything changes.